# Write a string after each method is complete on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

Recently I made a console program that updates an addon for me. I thought it would look better if I converted it from a console program to a JFrame/UI. Im pretty much a beginner but I don't seem to find anywhere how I can add text to JFrame/Panel after each method is completed. A bit like a progress bar but just text discribing what's happening 'under the hood'. Nothing fancy but atleast a bit more visual than when I run my jar and all I see is a windows loading ring spinning for a few seconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Updater");

    JLabel label1=new JLabel("Testprogram 1",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label2=new JLabel("Method 1..",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label3=new JLabel("Method 3..",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label4=new JLabel("Method 4...",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label5=new JLabel("Done!",JLabel.LEFT);

    JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(label3);
    panel.add(label4);
    panel.add(label5);

    CreateFrame();
    Start();
    CreateDir();
    LinkList();
    Download();
    unzip();
    DeleteZip();

}
```

I tried adding the labels after each method but I guess it wont work like that unless it "updated" in realtime. I hope someone understands what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Method names should not start with an upper case character. Show me a method from the API that does start with an upper case character. Learn by example and don't make up your own conventions as other people will not be able to read your code.

Comment: I'll remember that. Kinda confusing jumping between C# and Java.

Comment: I don't often say this but you accepted a bad answer, one that will risk Swing threading issues. If he started his Swing GUI correctly, on the Swing event thread, or if you try to use his code in any other Swing program, it will lock up, and you will end up with the same problem you began with. For an example of corrected code, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have a long-running bunch of code that is tying up your GUI preventing it from painting and interacting with the user. If so, You need to read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to see why your program is not behaving as you'd expect it.

---

Note that dani-h's example will risk Swing threading issues since he is calling Thread.sleep(...) on the same thread where he is calling his Swing code. If he started his Swing GUI correctly, on the Swing event thread, or if you try to use his code in any other Swing program, it will lock up, and you will end up with the same problem you began with.

Below is a corrected code using dani-h's example, but correcting his threading issues by using a SwingWorker:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Example2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 200;
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();

   public Example2() {
      add(label);
      final MySwingWorker mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker();
      mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (MySwingWorker.STEP_PERFORMING.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               label.setText(mySwingWorker.getStepPerforming());
            } else if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
               Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Example2.this);
               win.dispose();
            }
         }
      });
      mySwingWorker.execute();
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      Example2 example = new Example2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example 2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(example);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> { 
   public static final String STEP_PERFORMING = "step performing";
   private static final long SLEEP_DELAY = 1500;
   private String stepPerforming = "";

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      start();
      createDir();
      linkList();
      download();
      unzip();
      deletezip();
      return null;
   }


   public String getStepPerforming() {
      return stepPerforming;
   }


   public void setStepPerforming(String stepPerforming) {
      String oldValue = this.stepPerforming;
      String newValue = stepPerforming;
      this.stepPerforming = stepPerforming;
      firePropertyChange(STEP_PERFORMING, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   private void start() {
      setStepPerforming("Starting...");
      // Start();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   private void createDir() {
      setStepPerforming("Executing Create Directory");
      // CreateDir();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   private void linkList() {
      setStepPerforming("Executing Link List");
      // LinkList();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   private void download() {
      setStepPerforming("Executing Download");
      // Download();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   private void unzip() {
      setStepPerforming("Executing Unzip");
      // unzip();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   private void deletezip() {
      setStepPerforming("Executing Delete zip");
      // DeleteZip();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

}
```

Comment: +1 Testing the code where each method just prints the method name and then adds the label after returning from the method and it works as expected